# Calculate the difference between two field counts as a part of the pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table

This issue is driving me mad after a couple hours and I cannot find a solution for it. This solution is [close](https://superuser.com/q/901094/162488) but I don't have a third parameter like year to key on.

Here is the data I have in the pivot table:

```
Account ID (Rows area) - The account IDs

Count of Account ID (Values area) - This is how many rows are in the original data

Count of Reconciled (Values area) - How many entries have been reconciled

Values (Columns area - Excel makes this one by itself once I drag the other fields in place)
```

What I want in the 3rd "column" is:

**Remaining to Reconcile - The difference of `Count of Account ID` and `Count of Reconciled`.**

Visual of what I want:

```
Account ID | Count of Account ID | Count of Reconciled | Remaining to Reconcile
ID-1234    | 500                 | 300                 | 200
```

**I can do the math next to the pivot table but then I cannot sort or do anything else since then you will get an error, so this is not a valid solution.**

Comment: What is your data source?  Do you have the ability to modify the source?  The ideal solution that comes to mind is a simple boolean flag for reconciled T/F that you can use for your columns.  Then you can sort/filter all you like without any trouble.

Comment: Better attach the Worksheet, help us to understand the Data illustration.